# angular @version v2.0.3 throwing error

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

[image]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at TooltipFactory (scripts/lib/angular-strap.js:3147:43)
    at scripts/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js:2209:10
    at Object.d [as invoke] (scripts/lib/angular.min.js:34:265)
    at scripts/lib/angular.min.js:43:447
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at q (scripts/lib/angular.min.js:7:280)
    at Object. (scripts/lib/angular.min.js:43:414)
    at Object.d [as invoke] (scripts/lib/angular.min.js:34:265)
    at scripts/lib/angular.min.js:36:13
    at Object.c [as get] (scripts/lib/angular.min.js:34:13)

Please see the attached image. Why this issue happening? How to fix this?

Comment: Post your code please..

Comment: guys, I tried  this way   angular.module('myApp', [ 'mgcrea.ngStrap.modal', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.aside', 'mgcrea.ngStrap.tooltip' ]); and it seems to be working.. The issue was with tooltip module. i removed it.

Comment: Your trying to debug with minified JS, aka `.min.js`. Use angular.js and you might get error msgs that are useful.

Comment: already tried that..but no help...:(

Answer (score -1):

Alirz: "i figured out
i am using ui.bootstrap and angular-strap. ui.bootstrap has a directive with name "popover" and this directive called $tooltip then when i use popover of angular-strap thats call $tooltip twice.
now you can delete popover directive on ui.bootstrap or u can change directive name . 
work for me"

https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/826

This worked for me as well
good luck!